# a complicated file copy and rename

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a lot of files in a specific directory. For example:

- I have a directory: `/home/scrivania/pdb_files` with contents:

  ```
  UN4_A.pdb
  VIV_A.pdb
  XMG_A.pdb
  Z34_A.pdb
  ZAR_A.pdb
  ZTW_B.pdb
  ```
- Moreover, I have a list of objects like this in a file (`"list.txt"`):

  ```
  VIV
  XMG
  ZTW
  ```

I want to copy from the working directory to another `/home/scrivania/news/` only the file that are present in the file `"list.txt"`.

At the end in the `news` directory I need to have only this 3 files:

```
VIV_A.pdb
XMG_A.pdb
ZTW_B.pdb
```

Also, with another script different from the first, I would like to rename the files in the new directory using only the first three characters of each file and the extention (.pdb). So, at the end the contents of the directory must look like this:

```
VIV.pdb
XMG.pdb
ZTW.pdb
```

Could someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: What if you have VIV_A.pdb and VIV_B.pdb in the original directory?

Comment: theoretically should not happen because I have deleted these cases and kept only files with the first three different characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the filename roots in an external file, you can use a bash loop to iterate over its content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s  nullglob

sourcedir=/home/scrivania/pdb_files
targetdir=/home/scrivania/news/

while IFS= read -r froot
do
    for file in "$sourcedir/$froot"*.pdb
    do
        cp "$file" "$targetdir/$froot.pdb"
    done
done < list.txt
```

- This will iterate over the entries in your file and then loop over all files which start with the three letters indicated and end in `.pdb`. Since you stated that there is only one such file in the source directory, this inner `for` loop will serve to single out the (unknown) exact filename from the pattern in `list.txt`. The `shopt -s nullglob` ensures that in the (unlikely) case no such file exists, the loop will not stumble upon it.
- In the "inner" `for` loop, the script will then copy the file to the target directory. In its current form it renames the files while copying in the way you specified. If this is not what you want, change the line to

  ```
  cp "$file" "$targetdir"
  ```

  and do the renaming in a second script.
- If you are quite sure that there always will be exactly one file that starts with your three letters, you can omit the `for` loop and replace it with

  ```
  cp "$sourcedir/$froot"*.pdb "$targetdir/$froot.pdb"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
input="files.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
 /bin/cp "${line}_A.pdb" "/home/scrivania/news/${line}.pdb"
done
```

Should do it.

Comment: What about those files where the suffix is `_B.pdb`?

Comment: don't consider the suffix, but only the first three characters

Comment: where are the files copy ? in which direcotry?

Comment: Clarified. @AdminBee the suffix is considered non-essential from the comments above.

Comment: @stoney That was not quite my point. Your script would only copy those files that end in `_A.pdb`, although the OP stated in the examples that there are files which end in `<three letters>_B.pdb`.

Comment: i Would like a script that not consider the suffix, but only the first three characters

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

for XXX in $(cat list.txt)
do
  cp /tmp/home/scrivania/pdb_files/${XXX}*.pdb /tmp/home/scrivania/news/$XXX.pdb
done
```

Comment: Notice the question tag states `bash` ...

Comment: @AdminBee  it's a question of principle.

Comment: Ok, then of course ... ;)